# How to manage Autolayout constraints which can be applicable for iOS 7 & iOS 6.0 both

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I have created the new iOS project in xCode 5 with deployment target 6.0 and Apply Pin constraint [Bottom space to superview] to make AutoLayout applicable for iOS 7 as well iOS 6.0 with different devices but

When I choose option "View as : " : iOS 7.0 & later Button looks like following

[image]

then When I change option "View as : " : iOS 6.0 & earlier the button looks like following

[image]

How Do I manage constrait such a way that make applicable with iOS 6.0 & iOS 7.0 both ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What is the full set of constraints on the button?

Comment: I have already mention this in my question that constraint i am using is Pin [Bottom space to superview] constraint only no any other constraints except that .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue in my story board, I searched a lot with no hope and ended up removing all constrains by:

**Editor -> Resolve Auto-Layout Issues -> Clear all constraints in view controller**

Then reordering again, this solved most of my issues.

First from Apple Transition Guide:

> If business reasons require you to continue supporting iOS 6 or
>   earlier, you need to choose the most practical way to update the app
>   for iOS 7. The techniques you choose can differ, but the overall
>   advice remains the same: First, focus on redesigning the app for iOS
>   7. Then, bring the changes to the iOS 6 version as appropriate.

This means that you could face some issues in prior iOS versions, especially in layout and you need to re-layout your controls under `iOS7` then test them under `iOS6`.

Comment: Yes, I observed that thing when I had created a sample project in xCode 5 then placed one UILabel object on Main View after that I have viewed that thing in both for iOS 7 and later & iOS 6 & earlier the position i was getting were different in both the cases.

Comment: @brij: Then how are you following to support both iOS6 and iOS7?

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an app that runs on both iOS 6 and iOS 7.  Some of my buttons appear the same on both iOS 6 and iOS 7 and some appear to be vertically smaller on iOS 6 but normal on iOS 7.   I looked and the difference appears to be that on the buttons which maintain their size, I am using a background image like so.

```
//...background button images are 33wx44h and 66wx88h.  these correspond to the
//   two name variations; <name>.png and <name>@2x.png.  the former is used for
//   standard resolution screens and the latter for retina screens.
//   the UIEdgeInsetsMake is specifically set to 0, 16, 0, 16 (tp,lf,by,rt) so
//   that we have no vertical stretching because Apple's preferred button size,
//   vertically, is 44.  horizontally, the button is 33w and we lock 16 from
//   the left and 16 from the right to leave only a single vertical row of pixels
//   to be stretched horozontally; which is the most efficient; processing wise.

UIEdgeInsets insets   = UIEdgeInsetsMake( 00.0f,16.0f,00.0f,16.0f );  // tp,lf,bt,rt
UIIMage *    btnImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: myImage ]
                          resizableImageWithCapInsets: insets];
[button setBackgroundImage: btnImage
                  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

I'm thinking that in my situation, I can put a background image into all of them, even if it is transparent, to maintain the same look.

Hope that's helpful.